# Как передать массив как параметр строки GET-запроса в Java (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

Цель - сделать api более RESTful. Для получения ресурсов должен использоваться метод GET, но для получения списка ресурсов в контроллер должен передаваться фильтр такого вида:

```
@Data
public class Filter {
    private int limit;
    private List<Sort> sort;

    public Filter(int limit, List<Sort> sort) {
        this.limit = limit;
        this.sort = sort;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class Sort {
    private String name;
    private String direction;
}
```

Из-за наличия списка `List<Sort>` внутри фильтра, возникают проблемы с получением его в контроллере.

Тщательно изучив [мануал](https://lankydan.dev/2017/03/11/passing-data-transfer-objects-with-get-in-spring-boot) и [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam) на тему передачи объектов в строке GET-запроса, мне так и не удалось добиться успеха. По-прежнему неясно, в каком виде надо передать массив с клиента, и что сделать на сервере, чтобы он его увидел как список (происходят разного вида ошибки при маппинге фильтра).
Использую такую стратегию (для получения всего, кроме списка):

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<SomeDTO> getList(@RequestParam("filter") String filterJson) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Filter filter = null;
        try {
            filter = mapper.readValue(filterJson, Filter.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return getSomeDtos(filter);
    }
```

Запрос с клиента:

```
http://localhost:3000/some-api?filter=%7B%22limit%22:10,%22sort%22:null%7D
```

**Уважаемые знатоки, вопрос - в каком виде надо передать List<> в фильтре в строке GET-запроса?**

Comment: А что вообще такое CustomSort и почему вы передаете его как массив?

Comment: @NarasuOo, это сортировка. Передаю их как массив, потому что этого требует логика приложения.

Comment: Вот такое простое и гениальное решение предлагает иностранный гражданин https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/353090 (конечно если вы понимаете иностранные знаки:) Рядом можно найти другой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Решение вашей задачи для контроллера:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExampleController {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @GetMapping
    @SneakyThrows
    public Filter getSorted(@RequestParam( name = "filter") String filter) {
        log.info("Input string is {}", filter);
        Filter mapped = mapper.readValue(filter, Filter.class);
        log.info("Filter dto is {}", filter);
        return mapped;
    }
}
```

Чтобы это решение заработало, запрос нужно полностью приводить в url encoded вид. Например, запрос для объекта вида

```
{
  "limit": 12,
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "direction": "direction"
    }
  ]
}
```

Будет выглядеть так:

**http(s)://{host}:{port}/?filter=%7B%22limit%22%3A12%2C%20%22sort%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22name%22%2C%20%22direction%22%3A%20%22direction%22%7D%5D%7D**

[Здесь](https://www.urlencoder.org/) - можно перевести в url-encoded вид и обратно

Подробнее про url encoding можно прочесть хотя бы [на вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

И немного бубнежа от меня:

1. Может быть вам вместо объекта использовать набор параметров для фильтрации? Параметров limit и direction, как правило, достаточно для большинства задач
2. Добавьте валидацию в dto запроса, если решите его оставить (может ли лимит быть null? или direction? - от ответа на эти вопросы сильно зависит дизайн и будущее всего апи - и клиентов тоже)
3. В контроллере не должно быть никакой логики (даже если вы в качестве примера привели инициализацию ObjectMapper и маппинг строки в объект)
4. Выносите в конфигурацию всего приложения инициализацию ObjectMapper, делайте метод его создания бином и затем инжекьте его во все сервисы.
5. Не забудьте где-нибудь прописать ExceptionHandler для ошибок маппинга.

Удачи!